# How to extend session timeout runtime?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session

I have web application in asp.net . in order to stay user logged in some how i need to extend session timeout value at runtime. suppose it is 30 min initial. and upto 29 min use not had any activity and suddenly he click some button on page at this glance there should be remaining  1 min + 30 min should extend. is this possible ? how to do that or is this internally managed in .net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, this is the default behavior. ASP.NET implements a rolling timeout mechanism that only terminates the session information for a user if no request is received within the timeout period, but it resets the "clock" everytime a new request related to the session is received.

Comment: perhaps it right..but what i am experiencing is bit opposite here. though i set my timeout 30 mins and suppose had no activity from 20 mins...suddnly it expiring after 10 mins... so i can not think it is handled in asp.net. if there it is ... i would good isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Session.Timeout = 60;

this will set the session timeout to 60 minutes.

Comment: oops!!! I know that and i explained in question also. please read my question again.

Answer (score 0):

There are several websites that output a small snippet of script on each page render that includes a JavaScript timer that is set to run about 2 minutes before the session timeout. If your session time out is 5 minutes, the script would be set to fire after 3 minutes.

The script would popup a modal window of some sort of warning saying "Your session is about to expire, click here to stay logged in". The button on that popup would either refresh the current page or do some AJAX to send a request to the server, refreshing the session time out. At that point you would want to re-create the timer in JavaScript incase the user is idle.